# return value shows variable might not have been initialise while using if else

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, return, adapter

I am using recycler view and creating a popular list of video ..and I have 2 viewholder 1 for **Photo** another for **Video** I use this code for differentiating photo and video ...but when I return view type using **if else** it shows it is not initialise ...how can I solve this is there any new way I can do this.
**this is my image**
[image]
*this is my code*

```
public class Trending_adapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
private static final int VIDEO_TYPE=0;
private static final int IMAGE_TYPE=1;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private VideoHolder mVideoHolder;
private PhotoHolder mPhotoHolder;
private int viewType;
  class PhotoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
      public PhotoHolder(View view){
        super(view);

    }
}
class VideoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    static final int LAYOUT_RES = R.layout.main_list;
    private ExoPlayerViewHelper helper;
    private CircleImageView profile_image;
    //private String likeString;
    public VideoHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
    }     
}


public Trending_adapter(List<Photo> moviesList) {
    this.moviesList = moviesList;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //findViewById...
    mContext = parent.getContext();
    switch (viewType) {
        case VIDEO_TYPE:
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.video_type, parent, false);
            mContext = parent.getContext();
            return new VideoHolder(v);
        case IMAGE_TYPE:
            View i = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.main_list, parent, false);
            mContext = parent.getContext();
            return new PhotoHolder(i);
    }
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    // mHolder = holder;
    // photo = getItem(position);
    //   photo = moviesList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
    //  final VideoHolder viewHolder2 = (VideoHolder)holder;
    int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
    switch ( viewType ) {
        case IMAGE_TYPE:

            break;
        case VIDEO_TYPE:


            break;

    }


}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return moviesList.size();
}
@Override
public int getItemViewType ( int position ) {
    int compare;
    int viewType ;
  if(moviesList.get(position).getPopularlist().contains("true")){
      if (moviesList.get(position).getType_post().contains("Photo")) {
          viewType = IMAGE_TYPE;
      } else {
          viewType = VIDEO_TYPE;
      }
  }
    return viewType = over here it shows in red underline under view type;
}
public Photo getItem(int position) {
    return moviesList.get(position);
```

Comment: why I have only problem with this return viewtype

Comment: post your whole adapter code

Comment: okk I will .......

Comment: simple make the `viewType` as global variable

Comment: please take a look at this please

Comment: vm345 take a look at this

Comment: where are you declaring `VIDEO_TYPE` and `IMAGE_TYPE`

Comment: sorry I forgot to cut that wait ill edit this once again

Comment: yes please ..I have edited it..please say me what is the problem

Comment: You should declare your variable `viewType` in Trending_adapter

Comment: bro I have new error come on chat please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you have not given any view type in the false case of your if condition

```
  if(moviesList.get(position).getPopularlist().contains("true"))
```

In `getItemViewType` initiallize `int viewType` with a default value.

```
  int viewType = IMAGE_TYPE; // default view type
```

Full code is

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType ( int position ) {
    int compare;
    int viewType = DEFAULT_TYPE; // provide a default view if all conditions fail

    // rest of the code

    return viewType;
}
```

Comment: this if(moviesList.get(position).getPopularlist().contains("true")) is not working

Comment: Not working as in? What is the error? You need to provide a default view type to avoid __variable not initialized__ error

Comment: yes I did as you did...your code is right but I don't want to display photo if condition fails how can I do this

Comment: please tell me ..bro

Comment: You can provide one more view type which shows any error information that usually happens when all your conditions inside `getItemViewType` fail. Make that your default view type, or return it in the else case of your `if` condition. Here compiler error shows because you have not given any view type in the else case of your `if`

Comment: when I do that it acquires space in recycler view when I scroll down

Comment: Did you give one more view type? And corresponding `View` in `onCreateViewHolder`?

Comment: What do you want to display in the recycler view when `if(moviesList.get(position).getPopularlist().contains("true"))` this condition fails?

Comment: yes I gived one more view type  that why I acquiring space

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174080/discussion-between-new-learner-and-sarath-kn).

Comment: I want if this condition fails I want this to be no triggers

Answer (score 0):

Just add another field in you model class :

```
class Photo{
    public static final int VIDEO_TYPE=1;
    public static final int IMAGE_TYPE=2;
    // your fileds
    public int type;// ( update this field at the time of building your list
                      //apply your logic for differentciate VIDEO_TYPE & IMAGE_TYPE )
    }
```

update type as VIDEO_TYPE OR IMAGE_TYPE;

```
    public class Trending_adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

        ArrayList<Photo> moviesList=new ArrayList<>();

        public Trending_adapter(List<Photo> moviesList) {
            this.moviesList = moviesList;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            //findViewById...
            mContext = parent.getContext();
            switch (viewType) {
                case Photo.VIDEO_TYPE:
                    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.video_type, parent, false);
                    mContext = parent.getContext();
                    return new VideoHolder(v);
                case Photo.IMAGE_TYPE:
                    View i = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.main_list, parent, false);
                    mContext = parent.getContext();
                    return new PhotoHolder(i);
            }
            return null;
        }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType ( int position ) {
    return moviesList.get(position).type;
       }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return moviesList.size();
    }

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

Photo model=moviesList.get(position);
    switch ( model.type ) {
        case IMAGE_TYPE:
            //do your stuff here for IMAGE_TYPE type
            break;
        case VIDEO_TYPE:
          //do your stuff here for VIDEO_TYPE type
            break;

    }


}


        class VideoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            static final int LAYOUT_RES = R.layout.main_list;
            private ExoPlayerViewHelper helper;
            private CircleImageView profile_image;
            //private String likeString;
            public VideoHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
            }     
        }


        class PhotoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
              public PhotoHolder(View view){
                super(view);

            }
        }

        }

It works fine for you.
```